# Need help understanding 16QAM constellation diagram

Tags: modulation, demodulation

Is the identification of each point on the constellation diagram arbitrary as long as the sender and receiver know the mapping?

I have seen some diagrams which order in an outward spiral, while others go left to right. Does it matter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes and no.

The mapping is arbitrary as long as the receiver correctly determines which constellation point a symbol is.  If the receiver makes a mistake, though, it is most likely going to pick a "neighbor" constellation point (i.e. a constellation point that is only one spot away).  It is highly unlikely that a correctly implemented receiver will pick a constellation point far away from the transmitted point.  Communication systems try to mitigate the impact of the "neighbor" mistakes by minimizing the [Hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) between neighbors.  A map where all of the nearest neighbors have a Hamming distance of 1 is called a [Gray](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) map.  If you use a Gray map almost all of the symbol errors will only result in one bit error.

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on what you mean by *identification*.  The *four* bits associated with each constellation point are arranged so that along any row (or any column)
two of the four bits are fixed and the other two change in *Gray code* order.
Different people (and standards) might use different choices for which
two bits change along rows and which two change along columns. For
example, if the first two bits change on the Q axis and the last two
bits on the I axis, the assignment is as shown.
$$\begin{array}{l|l|l|l}
1111 & 1110 & 1100 & 1101\\
\hline
1011 & 1010 & 1000 & 1001\\
\hline
0011 & 0010 & 0000 & 0001\\
\hline
0111 & 0110 & 0100 & 0101
\end{array}
$$ but different Gray code orderings could also be used (e.g.
$00, 01, 11, 10$ instead of the $11,10,00,01$ from top to bottom
and left to right shown above.
If you want to label the constellation points as $s_0, s_1, \ldots, s_{15}$,
you can do so in any way you wish including the spiraling out from
the origin, but if you want the subscripts to match any straightforward
and commonly used mapping from integers $[0, 15]$ to $4$-bit nybbles, that is more complicated.